# Remote SSH in Visual Studio Code: Build with make, fix build errors, and debug

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, makefile, remote-access

I have a project in C++ in a remote server.
The project uses Cmake to generate a makefile, and then I execute `make <params>` to build depending on the target, etc.

I typically used xRDP to connect, and then I worked with Eclipse CDT, which provided with several useful capabilities:

1. I had configured several make targets, so I could quickly build variously by double clicking.
2. After building attempts, I could easily navigate to the code lines with errors/warnings by double clicking. Note that Eclipse has (at least) two ways of putting together its list of *Problems*: 2.1. From the output of the build process. 2.2. From its own *Code Analysis*. This is faster since it does not require building, but its output is not always reliable, it may report false positives. One can turn off *Code Analysis* to avoid this nuisance if need be.
3. After building, I could debug.

I mean to get the same capabilities with VSCode under Remote SSH.
I looked for several extensions, but I found no way of achieving remotely items 1-3 above.

Is that even possible?